# difference between odata webapi and RESTier?

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, odata, restier

I am looking at implementing an odata solution and both [web api](https://github.com/OData/WebApi) and [RESTier](https://github.com/OData/RESTier) are listed as viable v4 odata libraries in the [odata.org libraries](http://www.odata.org/libraries/). They both seem to use [odata core](https://github.com/OData/odata.net).

1. What are the differences?
2. I am looking into specifically implementing open types, how is the support for that feature in both?

Comment: What do you mean with "open types"?

Comment: @PatrickHofman I want to extend my resources to have dynamic properties. The webapi documentation mentions it. http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#04-10-open-type-in-untyped-scenarios .

Comment: Okay. I am not familiar with those. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 4):

You can't compare them both. RESTier builds on top of Web API to allow an faster development process by automating some parts of the framework.

It serves as kind-of middelware between WebAPI and you. RESTier extends filtering, security and a lot of other things you normally would need to code by hand.